# How to render array of JSON data in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning React and came across a slightly tricky problem for my level. From my API call I get a response which is an array of objects. I want to display this in a list. To get the idea of how the response looks, this is an example (it is array of JSON)

```
data = [
  {0: {name: "tom"}},
  {1: {name: "Pope"}},
  {2: {name: "jack"}}
 ];
```

To render this information in my container I try something like this:

```
render() {
  const items = data.map((d) => <li>{d.name}</li>);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But it's not printing anything. I don't even get any error. I think the way I am parsing the response is wrong.

What is the correct way to solve my tricky problem?

Comment: if it really is JSON, then you have to parse it using JSON.parse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the

```
const items = data.map((d) => <li>{d.name}</li>);
```

Your `d` is the object: `{0: {name: "tom"}`, not only `{name: "tom"}`

So you will need to take the value for each such object first.

This (although probably not optimal) will do the job:

```
const items =data.map((d) => {
  const val= Object.values(d)[0];
  return (<li>{val.name}</li>)
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the way you are extracting the data. The reference `d` is to an object that contains a 0, 1, 2 property, which values is another object that contains a `name` property.

Based on the pattern of the object you can get the `name` object by using the current index:

```
const items = data.map((d,i) => (<li>{d[i].name}</li>));
```

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [
  {0: {name: "tom"}},
  {1: {name: "Pope"}},
  {2: {name: "jack"}}
];

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
        const items = this.props.data.map((d,i) => (<li>{d[i].name}</li>));

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo data={data} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: based on the pattern of the object you can achieve what you want by doing this as the index

        const items = this.data.map((d,i) => {
            return(<li>{d[i].name}</li>) 
        });

else the other option is to extract the inner objects so the iterator would have direct access to the name property on the object.

Comment: here's a reference to why it makes sense at least to me I'm assuming react is using the same params as the native map operator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Hey Dr. your idea works, and is really easy to implement. *Move the comments into the answer*. You can copy my demo code, and show your solution.

Comment: Thanks Ori, as long as the OP figured out his issue I'm happy thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure the OP actually read your answer, and the comments.  In addition, even if the OP selected another answer, other people might find your solution useful. You need to format the text, add include your solution in the answer, and not in the comments. Since your solution was really nice, I've inserted it to the answer. If you don't like my changes to can revert them or edit manually.

Comment: Cool beans thanks Ori noted I'm new to the whole formatting will take my time next time :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as [@rafahoro explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165339/5157454), it sthat each object contains a unique property, and the actual object with the value is inside that property.

If you can, change the API, so the response would be simple objects. The other options are to extract the value from each object, or ff the properties in the objects are incremental (0, 1, 2 like the example), you can convert it to an object using by:

1. Merge all object, into one by spreading the array into [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
2. Add the length property
3. Convert back to an array using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

   const arr = Array.from(Object.assign({ length: data.length }, ...data));

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [
  {0: {name: "tom"}},
  {1: {name: "Pope"}},
  {2: {name: "jack"}}
];

const arr = Array.from(Object.assign({ length: data.length }, ...data));

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const items = this.props.data.map((d) => <li>{d.name}</li>);

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo data={arr} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```